# Prove $T$ continuous if and only if $T$ bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Let $X$, $Y$ be normed space and
$$T:D(T)\subseteq X\to Y$$ be linear operator.

Prove $T$ continuous if and only if $T$ bounded.

$(\Leftarrow)$

Given $T$ bounded, so there exist $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Vert T(x)\Vert\leq c\Vert x\Vert$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$, we choose $\delta=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{c} >0$ such that $\forall x\in D(T)$ with $$\Vert x-a\Vert<\delta.$$

We can see that 
$$\Vert T(x)-T(a)\Vert=\Vert T(x-a)\Vert\leq c\Vert x-a\Vert<c\delta= \varepsilon.$$

So, we can conclude that $T$ continuous function.

Is it correct proof? Please correct if I made mistake.

$(\Rightarrow)$

Given T continuous, so for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in D(T)$ with $\Vert x-a\Vert<\delta$ imply $\Vert T(x)-T(a)\Vert<\varepsilon$.

$$\Vert T(x)-T(a)\Vert=\Vert T(x-a)\Vert<\varepsilon.$$

Now I confuse how to prove $\Vert T(x)\Vert\leq c\Vert x\Vert$, for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$

Anyone can give me hint how to proof this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since T is continuous. We can find $\delta>0$ such that if $||x||<\delta$ we have that  $$||Tx||<1$$

Now, for all $x\in D(T)$, $x\neq 0$ $$||Tx||=||\frac{||x||}{\delta}T(\frac{\delta x}{||x||})||\leq \frac{1}{\delta}||x||$$

Comment: How do we get the "$\leq$" sign? I know $\lt$ implies $\leq$ and we can make it look more like the definition of boundedness, but is it strictly the case here?